# Subclass of QGraphicsLayoutItem for stretchers?

Tags: c++, qt, qt4

The specializations of QGraphicsLayout (e.g. QGraphicsLinearLayout) include an insertStretch method.

What kind of object do QGraphicsLinearLayout::insertStretch method insert in the list of items managed by the layout? Better asked: what type of object is returned by QGraphicsLayout::itemAt method when called for a stretch position?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've never investigated this, so I don't know, but if you are truly curious, you could ask for an object at that position.  Assuming it doesn't return `NULL`, you could then work your way through the meta information and find out quite a bit of information about it.

I wouldn't be too surprised, however, if it were a stock `QWidget` (empty, drawing nothing).

Comment: I was lazy, so I asked. I think I have no other choice so to proceed in the way you said :)